# docker-compose doesn't see contents of a particular directory

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I've got a docker-compose.yml file that mounts the current directory as a volume to /app in a container.  The .yml looks something like this:

```
version: "3"
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/Dockerfile-commandbox
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    environment:
      - TZ=${TIMEZONE-America/Los_Angeles}
```

Pretty basic.

Now, when I ssh into that container and navigate to the /app directory, it can *see* the `./wwwroot` folder, but its contents are empty, despite *not* being empty on my host machine.  Performing a directory listing on the wwwroot folder in the container displays no results; whereas the folder has lots of content.

[image: wwwroot exists... but has no files in it]

What would be causing the container to *not* be able to see the contents of the wwwroot folder?

The Dockerfile-commandbox file is pretty straightforward as well.

```
FROM ortussolutions/commandbox:4.8.0
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    net-tools \
    tzdata \
    vim \
 && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
COPY scheduled/scheduled-tasks.cfm /app/
WORKDIR /app
RUN box server start cfengine=lucee@5.3.7.47 port=8080 serverHomeDirectory=/root/serverHome host=0.0.0.0 openbrowser=false saveSettings=false heapSize=4096 minHeapSize=4096 \
    && box config set server.defaults.app.cfengine=lucee@5.3.7.47 server.defaults.web.AJP.enable=true \
    && curl -sS http://localhost:8080/scheduled-tasks.cfm \
    && box server stop
```

**UPDATE**
To be clear, there are other files in the directory structure and each one is visible, with its contents, from the container.
[image: Directory structure]

Comment: Is the host directory a mount point, or otherwise some kind of non-standard directory?

Comment: @DavidMaze It is not.  It's just a standard run-of-the-mill directory on the file system.

Comment: Could it be a permission issue?

Comment: From whence do the contents or wwwroot come?

Comment: @RobertMoskal I don't think I understand your question?

Comment: @JulienB I checked permissions... no problem there.

Comment: I seem no problem in docker as I can see now. Not enough info. Could you build image manually and `docker run --mount type=volume,src=.=/app <image_name> /bin/bash` (if no `bash`, instead `sh`) to search for `/app/wwwroot`?

Comment: @AkihitoKIRISAKI I can see the wwwroot folder in the docker container.  That's not a problem.  It creates /app in the container and every other file is listed, but for whatever reason the wwwroot directory is empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This must have been a glitch in Docker.  On 12/18 release 3.0.2 was available.  Installing the update, and bringing up the containers made the issue go away.  To confirm I rolled back to 3.0.1, and witnessed the issue again.  I also did a full purge of my containers by running `docker system prune -a` and rebuilding everything from scratch.

As of Docker Desktop Community edition for Mac 3.0.2, this is no longer an issue.